# How to execute this Oracle statement on JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have trouble executing the following using a JDBC prepared statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Time_trg BEFORE INSERT ON Time FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  SELECT Time_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :new.id FROM dual; 
END;
```

The code:

```
try {
   PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement( sql );
   preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
} finally {
   statement.close();
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
```

I'm working on a database agnostic solution so I need something that is portable.  So what is oracle's problem?

Comment: The problem was PreparedStatement's named parameter syntax conflicts with Oracle's :new syntax, and there is no way to escape named parameters in PreparedStatements.  So you have use a Statement instead of PreparedStatement to subvert this little issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement`

```
OraclePreparedStatement statement = (OraclePreparedStatement)connection.prepareStatement( sql );
```

As this is much specific to Oracle, regular `PrepareStatement` doesn't help. Oracle provides a wrapper for the same, with additional functionalities as well.

Similarly, Oracle provides `OracleCallableStatement` similar to `CallableStatement`

**WorkAround:** (When PreparedStatement has to be used - Risk of being misused

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE EXECUTE_MY_DDL(INSTRING VARCHAR2)
 AS
 BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE INSTRING;
 END;
```

[Reference JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraint.htm#CHDIIDBE)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need a portable solution for this.  I don't want to use OraclePreparedStatement because that won't work on any other database.  What else can be done?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do it, as there's a special meaning for `:something`. You can try passing this String to a `PL/SQL` Block else.. Using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` .. Not a clean fix though.

Comment: It turns out I'm using OraclePreparedStatement under the hood.  The stacktrace shows OraclePreparedStatement on it.  Seems like if I used it then I'd have to do something specific to that API to make it work.  What would that be?

Comment: Oh `OraclePreparedStatement` should work, But your the one you attempt to execute is using `PreparedStatement` here

Comment: Well PreparedStatement is an interface that the jdbc driver authors implement, and it turns out the concrete class Oracle returns is a OraclePreparedStatementWrapper which uses an OraclePreparedStatement under that so technically I'm using one.  So if I have to use an OraclePreparedStatement I assume there is a special API I have to call on it to work otherwise what I'm doing would work.

Comment: Ah ok I just read the docs you attached and the problem is discussed in there.  I have to use Statement and not PreparedStatement.  That should be the portable solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to write our own stored procedure to do this. Oracle provides a built-in stored procedure we can use:  [DBMS_UTILITY.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_util.htm#ARPLS73238):

```
 DBMS_UTILITY.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT('create table t1 (id number)');
```

In fact this is safer than [the workaround procedure suggested in the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26080867/146325) as it doesn't allow the execution of DML and so is protected against SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot have any bind variables in Oracle DDL anyway, why use a `PreparedStatement`? You can use a static statement instead and shouldn't run into this problem:

```java
try (Statement s = connection.createStatement()) {
    s.executeUpdate(sql);
}
```