# How can i perform an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE from Java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I need to execute with a prepared statement an alter table inside an execute immediate but my coworker said me that its not possible with prepared statement, i can't test now if its true or not. Does someone knows if its possible or at least if something else exist ?

I have an interface with only strings where all my query are declared:
Something like this;

```java
String goofy = "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TABLE_X_BLADE NOLOGGING';";
```

can i execute that with a simple prepared statement ?

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm): "*The EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement executes a dynamic SQL statement or anonymous PL/SQL block. You can use it to issue SQL statements that cannot be represented directly in PL/SQL, or to build up statements where you do not know all the table names, WHERE clauses, and so on in advance.*" Why do you want to use this for such a simple `ALTER TABLE`?

Comment: I don't know, i need to adapt a packae in pl/sql in a Java Batch, i do not question.The only things i know is that the Execute immediate need when you have more query on the same table and you have the risk to lock the table with that

Comment: You don't need to use execute immediate here

Comment: You don't need execute immediate from Java. Use `Statement.execute(String)` with your DDL statement

Answer (score 0):

Try calling a stored procedure from your java code. that solves the problem. you can refer the below link. it would offer solution to your problem

[How to execute this Oracle statement on JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080786/how-to-execute-this-oracle-statement-on-jdbc)